# obfuscation tool for asp.net for html

Tags: asp.net, obfuscation

Is there a tool in which I am able to obfuscate the HTML rendered by ASP.NET dynamically?
That is, an IIS module that will produce a much harder HTML code to reverse engineer?

Thanks!

Comment: If you obfuscate the HTML, how will a browser be able to display it?

Comment: You obviously can't obfuscate HTML :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't obfuscate HTML beyond what browsers will interpret. This means you can remove all white space to make things rather unpleasant to read, but this would be trivial to format back to neatly tabbed code.

Do you really have a HTML layout that is so unique you are worried it will be copied? Surely your IP is either in the content or in the application rather than in the HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is only used to format your information. What makes your application special is the data processed in the back-end, unless your application is all written in client-side in javascript code, but I imagine that is not the case.

That said, you can minify your CSS and JS code. That will make these harder to read, but usually this minification is used to compress the files and reduce sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of precompiled HTML dlls and embedding scripts etc. as resources.